# Can a subscriber reply to a USSD Push message sent as a menu?

Tags: push, ussd

Is it possible to send a push USSD notification as a menu to a subscriber and have the subscriber respond to the notification in that same session?
E.g. Subscriber gets a push USSD message saying "You have a new voicemail. Send 1 to get it as an SMS, Send 2 to receive a web version".
The action on the button will be 'Reply'.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes. With USSD Push (Network Initiated) you create a session much like a handset initiated USSD request.